# How to redirect to login page if unauthorized user try to click? (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

My code is like this :

```
<script>
    export default{
        props:['idStore'],
        methods:{
            addFavoriteStore(event){
                $(function () {
                    $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, settings) {
                        if (xhr.status == 401) {
                            window.Laravel.baseUrl+'/login'
                        }
                        else {
                            event.target.disabled = true
                            const payload= {id_store: this.idStore}
                            this.$store.dispatch('addFavoriteStore', payload)

                            setTimeout(function () {
                                location.reload(true)
                            }, 1500)
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When click favorite button, it will call addFavoriteStore method

After run addFavoriteStore method, I will call condition to check unauthorized user or not. I try using condition like that, but it does not work. I check on the console, no error

Why the condition not working?

Comment: Never send authorized-only content to a page which is viewed by an unauthorized user. You can't prevent users to show/use everything on the page.

Comment: Surely if your using the normal Laravel routes and views in conjunction with vue components, then surely you can use Laravel to control whether a user is logged in or not, so you can then use a guard type situation and a blade directive like `@can('usebtn')` etc then display button if logged in if not hide or show a link to the log in to like this button???

Comment: Need more code you have and whether its in a balade view or your doing this as a SPA application etc

Comment: if your using blade, hence php it would not be disabled it would not show at all but you simply output a login button, so using the console to enable something that's not visible? So using laravel/php to display the correct button/link

Comment: if your using mainly js or spa type then use laravel API routes or place your routes behind the AUTH middleware and it would return a 'unauthenticated' response back so you can then check for that.

Comment: @Simon Davies, Great. It works. Thanks

Comment: what worked in the end?

Comment: @Simon Davies, I use condition like this : `@if (Auth::user())
    ...
@else`

Comment: added what i mentioned an answer :-)

Comment: @Simon Davies, Ok. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@moses-toh so glad my suggestions worked :-).

So going through it all you as you where using laravel and the blade syntax you can use Blade/PHP to check if the user is logged in  or not and supply the relivent Button/Message.  So like you have done:

```
   @if (Auth::user())
     <favorite-button>&heart; Favorite</favorite-button>
   @else
     <a href="{{route('login')}}">Login To Favorite</a>
   @endif
```

Hope this is ok.